# Configure alias with jq and multiple quotes

Tags: bash, alias, aws-cli, single-quotes

I'm trying to configure an alias that will give me a list of AWS resources and it keeps failing on escaping with single and double quotes.

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:tag,Values=foo1" "Name=bar,Values=foo2,foo3" | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[] | select(.Key=="Name") | .Value' | tr -d '"' |  sed -e 's/-pattern1.*//g' | sed -e 's/pattern2.*//g' | uniq
```

wrapping everything with single/double quotes does not work - `alias alias1='aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:tag,Values=foo1" "Name=bar,Values=foo2,foo3" | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[] | select(.Key=="Name") | .Value' | tr -d '"' |  sed -e 's/-pattern1.*//g' | sed -e 's/pattern2.*//g' | uniq'`

I'm trying to understand where shall I put the escaping characters

Comment: To shorten the story, use a function.

Comment: You can also probably use the `--query` option with `aws` to replace the use of `jq` altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using **alias** in the situation above will require escaping a lot of quotes

My best advice is to use a function

```
myFunc(){
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:tag,Values=foo1" "Name=bar,Values=foo2,foo3" | jq '.Reservations[].Instances[].Tags[] | select(.Key=="Name") | .Value' | tr -d '"' |  sed -e 's/-pattern1.*//g' | sed -e 's/pattern2.*//g' | uniq
 }
```

You can put it in your **.bashrc**.  Simply type **myFunc** to run the command

No need to escape quote! So simple, happy coding

Comment: "Use a function" is almost always the right answer to "I'm having trouble with an alias..."

Comment: Yea, you're welcome @NZL. If it solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted